# WPF ListBox size don't changed after unwrap

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have ListBox and dynamic DataTempletes Items.
When TextBlock text wrapping, ListBox size is adding and size changing when unwrapping doesn't return to old value and remains un-changed.
I don't understand what is the problem. TextBlock size changed but not ListBox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ctrlFavOdds"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding 'FavStakesList'}"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}"
                     AlternationCount="2"
                     FontWeight="Bold"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     IsHitTestVisible="False"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                                   Margin="2,0,5,0"
                                   Source="{Binding 'MakeExpressBetImage',   Converter={StaticResource 'imageconverter'}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Text="{Binding Stake}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                           Text="{Binding StakeFactor}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="14"/>
                            <Image  Grid.Column="3"
                                    Margin="5,0,2,0"
                                    Source="{Binding 'UpDounImage', Converter={StaticResource imageconverter}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

When TextBlock text wraping, ListBox size is adding and size changing when unwrapping doesn't return to old value and remains un-changed

Comment: What causes unwrapping? Is it `ListBox` width change?

Comment: height not change. If textBlox text wraping listBox ActualHeight adding but after that when text is small and unwrapping ListBox ActualHeight don't change and not reduced

Comment: This post help me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955591/my-listview-or-listbox-control-size-doesnt-shrink-when-there-is-a-complex-data